# How to a define a global constant from inside a function Javascript?

Tags: javascript, constants

I am building an application composed of a set of modules that get loaded when the application bootstrap:

```
const MODULES = []

function registerModules(config) {
  return modules.map(module => (new module(config)).install());
}

function bootstrap() {
  MODULES = registerModules({...}); 
}
```

The above of-course will raise an error. What I want to do is to assign the `MODULE` constant only when the app start but then it should be fixed. Is this possible?

Initialisation of `MODULES` has to happen inside `bootstrap` because of the config variable that I have to pass to `registerModules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indeed you want to:

- Have an initialised, but empty `MODULES` array during the time that `bootstrap()` is not yet called, and
- Make `MODULES` immutable once it has been populated, and
- Keep the current function signature of `registerModules` unchanged;

Then you could do it as follows:

```
function bootstrap() {
    Object.freeze(Object.assign(MODULES, registerModules({...}))); 
    // OR:
    // MODULES.push(...registerModules({...})); 
    // Object.freeze(MODULES);
}
```

If you don't insist on the existence of `MODULES` *before* `bootstrap()` is called, and you are open to store that information inside an object, then you could proceed as follows:

```
const globals = {};

function bootstrap() {
  globals.MODULES = registerModules({...});
  Object.freeze(globals.MODULES);
}
```

Once you are happy with `globals`, you can also freeze that object:

```
Object.freeze(globals);
```

Comment: To be complete, one could also freeze the individual modules, not just the MODULES variable... although the OP didn't mention if the individual modules should also be fixed.

Comment: thank you, it seems currently this the only available option, though it will only assure immutability but it still can be completely reassigned.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb, can you explain what you mean with *completely reassigned*? Neither `MODULES = `, nor `MODULES[0] = ` will work once `bootstrap()` has executed...

Comment: @trincot I mean `MODULES =`, because `MODULES[0] =` means object is mutable.

Comment: `MODULES = ` will not even work in your original code, because of `const`? That is the reason why I suggested `Object.assign`/`.push(...)`...

Comment: Sorry @trincot  I thought `assign` do not work on constant, thank you.